# Guides/tutorials for learning html5

Tags: html

Can anybody tell me a good tutorials for learning html5. a tutorial which is explaining the new features and the things droped etc. my sister is in 9th standard and knows html4. So i want to tell her a guide for html5. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tutorials:

- http://slides.html5rocks.com/#slide1
  (built using HTML5)
- http://html5tutorial.net/

Demos: http://html5demos.com/

Comment: +1 http://slides.html5rocks.com/ rocks! you go over the slides grasp HTML5 and smile :)

Comment: Ironic that the first link doesn't work on Firefox/3.6.15, slides get stuck half way...

Answer (score 2):

- [diveintohtml5.info](http://diveintohtml5.info)
- [html5rocks.com](http://html5rocks.com)

Comment: +1 for Dive into HTML5. By far the best HTML5 introduction for people already well versed in HTML 4.01 and/or XHTML.

Comment: Firstly get some book to read. Then go to practice . Html5rocks.com is good place to learn how to practice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

W3C guide is pretty long but very thorough http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff

Answer (score 0):

I learn by looking at what others have created, heres a nice HTML5 boiler plate setup
http://html5boilerplate.com/